# Luatex and Xetex installed but template isn't working

Tags: xetex

I have just downloaded a template from http://gtweb.uit.no/iwclul2015/2015-fiwclul.tar.gz

I've installed `luatex` and `xetex` but it's not compiling:

```
alvas@ubi:~$ sudo apt-get install texlive-xetex
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
texlive-xetex is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
alvas@ubi:~$ sudo apt-get install texlive-luatex
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
texlive-luatex is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

**Is there something else that I need to do to make it compile? Some other packages that i need to install?**

And it didn't compile into pdf and it's giving me this error in the build log:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(/home/alvas/git/papers2014/iwclul2015/.2015-fiwclul-template.tex.swp
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9h> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/polyglossia.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etex-pkg/etex.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/makecmds/makecmds.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3names.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3bootstrap.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3basics.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3expan.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3tl.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3seq.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3int.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3quark.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3prg.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3clist.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3token.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3prop.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3msg.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3file.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3skip.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3keys.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3fp.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3box.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3coffins.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3color.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3luatex.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3candidates.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty)

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty:41: Fatal fontspe
c error: "cannot-use-pdftex"
! 
! The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or LuaTeX to function.
! 
! You must change your typesetting engine to, e.g., "xelatex" or "lualatex"
! instead of plain "latex" or "pdflatex".
! 
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

l.41  }

/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty:41:  ==> Fatal er
ror occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on /tmp/.2015-fiwclul-template.tex.log.
```

Comment: Look at the first line of the log `This is pdfTeX, ` you have used pdflatex, you need to use xelatex or lualatex

Comment: How do I do that? (pardon my noobiness)

Comment: on the commandline you typeset `file.tex` by using `xelatex file` instead of `pdflatex file` If you are using an editor menu to send the command for you you need to configure the editor to do that which is of course editor specific.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Wanna write up a short answer?